# Fence post footings

Tags: fence, canada

I am looking to build about 60' of wooden fence, with 6x6 posts. I will hire a company to come and dig the holes, but I first wanted to find out the best way to fasten the posts.

I know that many fence posts go into the ground and concrete is then poured around them, but as I know from experience, replacing them is very difficult. Is it better nowadays to pour say, an 8" pier, and push a bracket into the wet concrete? And then bolt the post to the bracket?

Located in Ontario Canada, where I believe it is recommended to have at least 4' depth to prevent heaving.

Comment: In a high wind situation how well would you expect that bracket to hold? How long before the fasteners in the wood give way and the fence topples over? I think that having the posts 3-4 feet below the dirt, in concrete, will resist wind better than bracket could ever hope to achieve.

Comment: If you're going to surface-mount your fence post then you should be using metal posts. See https://www.perimtec.com/fence-mounted-to-concrete/

Comment: 6x6 posts is this a really tall fence or in a high wind area? Bed the post in concrete for best results treat the posts or purchase pressure treated lumber.

Comment: 6x6 fence posts seems excessive.

Comment: if you have a trailer hitch you can  hire a single operator post-hole digger for not much per hour.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the wind force, a connector like these may be just you need.

[image]

Comment: those beackets are for posts and columns that are braced or steadied at the top.
wind gusts will shake the fence until the fasteners quit and the post comes out.